# Is it okay to unsubscribe from a listener in its callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, next.js, redux-thunk

I have the following Thunk which deals with authentication flow for a web app I'm working on. It sets user authentication information in the Redux state. The onAuthStateChanged listener returns an unsubscribe function, and I need to call that at some point to prevent a memory leak. In the code below, I am calling the unsubscribe function from within the onAuthStateChanged callback function. Is this okay to do? In general, is it okay to unsubscribe from a listener within its callback?

```
export const frontEndAuthCheck = () => async dispatch => { 
  dispatch({
    type: actions.AUTH_CHECK_RESET_FRONT_END,
  });
  dispatch({
    type: actions.SET_TO_LOGGED_OUT_FRONT_END,
  });
  dispatch({
    type: actions.AUTH_CHECK_STARTED_FRONT_END,
  });

  let unsubscribeFunction;
  unsubscribeFunction = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( (user) => {
    if (user) {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.SET_TO_LOGGED_IN_FRONT_END,
      });
      dispatch({
        type: actions.AUTH_CHECK_COMPLETE_FRONT_END,
      });
    }
    else {
      dispatch({
        type: actions.AUTH_CHECK_COMPLETE_FRONT_END,
      });    
    }
    if (unsubscribeFunction) unsubscribeFunction();
  });
}
```

Comment: I suppose the alternative is saving *that* unsubscribe callback in state somewhere to be called by code later when you want to unsubscribe. Or refactor it to put the firebase logic in a redux-connected React context provider. Is there an issue with the above code or are you rather looking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'm a little new to all this and just trying to understand conceptually is it okay to unsubscribe from a listener within its callback? It's unclear to me if this will cause any problems.

Comment: Conceptually I believe it should work, in isolation. Now whether or not it works in the grander scheme of your app is more difficult to say without seeing it running in a browser or in integration testing.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the color.